# Python regex string match and replace at the same time

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string, replace

In Python, is there a way to search, return matched string, and replace matched strings all at the same time? See example below:

`a = "[fox] dog turtle [cat]"`

Goal:

```
result1 = "fox" #(first match inside bracket)
result2 = "cat" #(second match inside bracket)
result3 = "dog turtle" #(remaining string after removing matched text inside brackets
```

What I have:

```
result1, result2 = re.findall('\[.*?\]', a)
result3 = re.sub('\[.*?\]', '', a)
```

It seems redundant and clunky to have to run `re` twice. Is there a more elegant way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your code is Elegant enough and readable, but if you want to complicate things, There is not `function` that **return** matches
and **replace** them in the same time but you can use the force of `re.sub` that
accepts in `repl` argument a `function` that accept the matche as argument and
should return a `str` replacement, it's used for **dynamic replacing** `(example: when the replacing depends on the value of the match it self).`

```py
import re

a = '[fox] dog turtle [cat]'
matches = []
# append method of list return None so the return string is always `''`
# so when ever we find a match to replace we add it to matches list and replace it with `''`
# in your result you return the fox without brackets so i'm using a capture group inside the brackets
text = re.sub('\[(.*?)\]', lambda m: matches.append(m.group(1)) or '', a)

print(matches)  # ['fox', 'cat']
print(text)  # dog turtle
```

Comment: The only thing that you can get from the built-in function is the number of replacements performed by using `subn` instead of `sub`. But as you say there is no functionality that keeps track of the replacements performed, but you can easily achieve the same result manually as you have shown.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. The actual text string is actually much more complicated, so I'm already using ```subn``` to count the number of pattern instances. My main concern was not so much readability, but more about run time for duplicating search/replace for lots of lines.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. u made my day.

Comment: What does the <or ''> part do? Is that part of the lambda function? Or does the lambda function get evaluated first and it becomes something like <None or ''> during execution?

Comment: is this solution stable? I cannot find this behaviour documented anywhere

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex :

**Regex:**

```
\[(.*?)\].*?(\w[\w\s]+\w).*?\[(.*?)\]
```

[image: Regex]

**Python Code :**

```
import re

a = '[fox] dog turtle [cat]'
pattern = r'\[(.*?)\].*?(\w[\w\s]+\w).*?\[(.*?)\]'
res = re.search(pattern,a)
r1,r2,r3 = res.groups()
```

**Demo :** [Here](https://repl.it/repls/ScrawnyWorldlyConfiguration)

Comment: Thanks but my actual text strings are much more complicated, and bracketed words are not guaranteed to exist or ordered this way, so rigid patterns like this won't work.